# What math do I start with as an adult learner?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

I am hilariously bad at math. Even in High school I didn't reach past geometry, I just couldn't care less when I was in HS and didn't pay attention at all. When I did pay attention I was lost, frustrated and painfully confused. I'm 25 now with almost zero math skills. I am super interested in picking a STEM major but I feel like I need to start from square one as I am not even confident in my multiplication skills. What type of math do I start with and in what order? What exercises do I need to practice to become better at math?

Comment: How did the SAT/ACT go?  I would suggest picking up a practice book on the SAT Math Subject Tests.  I recall that Princeton has one, not sure if it's related to Princeton University or something else (don't be intimidated).  Start working through the book; you will be -shocked- at how simple these concepts are, going back to them as an adult.  I was the same, I didn't start college til I was 23 and didn't remember very much, but I got through the whole thing in like 3 weeks.  I was a truck driver before becoming a mathematician.

Just sign up for calculus and hope for the best!

Comment: "I am not even confident in my multiplication skills" Can you please elaborate on this? Is this just a confidence issue, or do you actually not understand things like order of operations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations ? This might just be a matter of you starting to read mathematics and do problems so that you remember the basics and regain confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you reached the point of studying functions, *Thomas' Calculus* by Hass, Heil, and Weir (now in it's 14th edition) is an excellent, modern textbook. It is full of great examples and exercises, which is critical for a beginner. This should help you achieve a strong foundation for further studies.

For reference, here is the first page of my text:

[image]

Comment: This is an introduction to calculus. As I understand the question OP wants to get from a little more than primary school maths to being able to take a calculus class. I don't think OP is at the level to be able to read that book.

Comment: @quarague It really depends on the precise details of what the OP means (see my comment). It could be that they're just out of practice and lack confidence, in which case, working through an introductory calculus textbook, beginning at the introduction to functions, and using online resources to fill in any gaps, might be the best way to proceed. If the OP truly hasn't learned the basics of algebra, then a more basic textbook is required. With regards to wanting to study STEM, the textbook I cited is an excellent choice.